# Clojure - Define a Data Structure For A Person

Tags: vector, data-structures, struct, clojure, logic

In other languages it is pretty self-explanatory in how to create a struct. How would you do something like this in Clojure?

For example, I'd like to add a person's first and last name, their address, and telephone numbers (home and mobile).

I'm guessing I'd want to make a vector?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Clojure, you would usually use a map to represent that sort of data. You could use a flat map:

```
{:first-name "Jeremy"
 :last-name "Martinson"
 :street "455 Larkspur Dr."
 :city "Baviera"
 :state "California"
 :zip 22611
 :home-phone "(555) 555-5555"
 :mobile-phone "(666) 666-6666"}
```

Or a nested one:

```
{:name {:first "Jeremy"
        :last "Martinson"}
 :address {:street "455 Larkspur Dr."
           :city "Baviera"
           :state "California"
           :zip 22611}
 :phones {:home "(555) 555-5555"
          :mobile "(666) 666-6666"}}
```

If your data has a more-or-less static schema and you want to make use of [Clojure's polymorphic features](http://clojure.org/reference/protocols), you could use [records](http://clojure.org/reference/datatypes):

```
(defrecord Name [first last])

(defrecord Address [street city state zip])

(defrecord Phones [home mobile])

(defrecord Person [name address phones])

(map->Person
 {:name (map->Name
         {:first "Jeremy"
          :last "Martinson"})
  :address (map->Address
            {:street "455 Larkspur Dr."
             :city "Baviera"
             :state "California"
             :zip 22611})
  :phones (map->Phones
           {:home "(555) 555-5555"
            :mobile "(666) 666-6666"})})
```

In this case, however, you'd probably want to just go with a map. That `Phones` record, in particular, is quite ugly.

Comment: Indeed, the phone a little on the "ugly" side for option 3. The first option is great because it is very simple, but the nested option is probably a little more of what I wanted. This looks very clean and concise - keeping everything in almost a table-like format. This way I can drag out all certain types of data at once... i mean personal info, address, and phones.

Thank you very much - I highly appreciate your EXTREMELY CLEAR elaboration.

Answer (score 1):

In clojure its called a "record", and is defined using [defrecord](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/defrecord):
from the docs:

```
(defrecord Person [fname lname address])
-> user.Person

(defrecord Address [street city state zip])
-> user.Address

(def stu (Person. "Stu" "Halloway"
           (Address. "200 N Mangum"
                      "Durham"
                      "NC"
                      27701)))
-> #'user/stu

(:lname stu)
-> "Halloway"

(-> stu :address :city)
-> "Durham"
```